# When useselector and usedispatch are used at the same time, Cause a Wireless loop

Tags: redux

I wanted to use hook to replace the troublesome connect, but it caused an incomprehensible problem,But,When using use selector and use dispatch at the same time, I first trigger the effects in modal, which will lead to a dead loop
。

## There are my  hook and modal  fileName: dict.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
/**

 * A Hook for get dict name
 * @param codes List
   */
   export function useDict(codes) {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   useEffect(() => {
   if (codes && dispatch) {
     dispatch({
       type: 'dict/getDict',
       payload: {
         codes
       },
     });
   }
   }, [dispatch, codes]);
   // select state
   const dict = useSelector(({ dict }) => dict);
   return dict.dictList;
   }

//  mock getDictData
const getDictData = () => new Promise((success, error) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    success({ name: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) });
  }, 100);
});
export default {
  namespace: 'dict',
  state: {
    dictList: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    loopData(state, action) {
      console.log('loopData', action.list);
      return { ...state, dictList: action.list };
    },
  },
  effects: {
    * getDict({ payload }, { call, put }) {
      const { codes } = payload;
      const response = yield call(getDictData, codes);
      yield put({
        type: 'loopData',
        list: response,
      });
        },
    },
};
```

## My App Index Page  fileName: index.js

```
import { useDict } from './dict.js';
const Index = () => {
const dictlist = useDict(['hello'])
 return <h1>Hello !!!</h1>
}
export default Index;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack! why does `useDict` take `codes` as argument? Aren't you getting the codes from redux in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line: `const dictlist = useDict(['hello'])` since `['hello']` is a new reference every time you render it causes the effect to run in useDict that causes the component to rerender and you have an infinite loop.

Since it's not clear where `['hello']` comes from I added an example how you can prevent re creating it unless it needs to be re created using React.useMemo.

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { useEffect, useState, useMemo } = React;

function useDict(codes) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (codes && dispatch) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'dict/getDict',
        payload: {
          codes,
        },
      });
    }
  }, [dispatch, codes]);
  // select state
  const dict = useSelector(({ dict }) => dict);
  return dict.dictList;
}

const initialState = {
  dict: [],
};
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === 'dict/getDict') {
    const { codes } = payload;
    return {
      ...state,
      dict: { dictList: codes[0].split('') },
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const App = () => {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState('ABC');
  //only re create dictArg if txt changed
  const dictArg = useMemo(() => [txt], [txt]);
  const dict = useDict(dictArg);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={txt}
        onChange={(e) => setTxt(e.target.value)}
      />
      dict:<pre>{JSON.stringify(dict, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```